# Bootstrap 5 multiple switches multiple colors

Tags: bootstrap-5

I have a site that needs to have around 10 switches to control colors for various items. The switches need to be color coded to the item...so around 10 colors, 1 for each switch.

I've tried everything I can, with no luck. They all use the same custom color I set.

```
    <div class="form-check form-switch">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" role="switch" id="flexSwitchCheckDefault" />
    <label class="form-check-label" for="flexSwitchCheckDefault">Label Text</label>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please provide some code. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can download my solution from [Github](https://github.com/Getsolutionhub/boostrap-5-multiple-switches-multiple-colors).

Output is can't provide properly because **.svg** file is missing. You can go in github website by click in above link and download full project with **.svg** file.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
        .check-color1:focus {
            border-color: #ff0000;
            outline: 0;
            box-shadow: 0 0 0 .25rem rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.25);
        }

        .check-color1:checked {
            border-color: red;
        }

        .check-color2:focus {
            border-color: #0d6efd;
            outline: 0;
            box-shadow: 0 0 0 .25rem rgba(0, 103, 255, 0.25);
        }

        .check-color2:checked {
            border-color: #0d6efd;
        }

        .check-color3:focus {
            border-color: #0dcaf0;
            outline: 0;
            box-shadow: 0 0 0 .25rem rgba(0, 212, 255, 0.25);
        }

        .check-color3:checked {
            border-color: #0dcaf0;
        }
        .check-color4:focus {
            border-color: #ffc107;
            outline: 0;
            box-shadow: 0 0 0 .25rem rgba(255, 193, 8, 0.25);
        }

        .check-color4:checked {
            border-color: #ffc107;
        }
        .check-color5:focus {
            border-color: #198754;
            outline: 0;
            box-shadow: 0 0 0 .25rem rgba(0, 255, 36, 0.25);
        }

        .check-color5:checked {
            border-color: #198754;
        }
        .check-color6:focus {
            border-color: #212529;
            outline: 0;
            box-shadow: 0 0 0 .25rem rgba(33, 37, 41, 0.25);
        }

        .check-color6:checked {
            border-color: #212529;
        }

        .form-switch .form-check-input:focus {
            /* For download below .svg image you can go github website and download project(link provided in above)  */
            background-image: url("download.svg");
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="container my-5">
        <div class="form-check form-switch">
            <input class="form-check-input check-color1 bg-danger" type="checkbox" role="switch"
                id="flexSwitchCheckChecked" checked>
            <label class="form-check-label" for="flexSwitchCheckChecked">Male</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check form-switch">
            <input class="form-check-input check-color2 bg-primary" type="checkbox" role="switch"
                id="flexSwitchCheckChecked" checked>
            <label class="form-check-label" for="flexSwitchCheckChecked">Male</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check form-switch">
            <input class="form-check-input check-color3 bg-info" type="checkbox" role="switch"
                id="flexSwitchCheckChecked" checked>
            <label class="form-check-label" for="flexSwitchCheckChecked">Male</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check form-switch">
            <input class="form-check-input check-color4 bg-warning" type="checkbox" role="switch"
                id="flexSwitchCheckChecked" checked>
            <label class="form-check-label" for="flexSwitchCheckChecked">Male</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check form-switch">
            <input class="form-check-input check-color5 bg-success" type="checkbox" role="switch"
                id="flexSwitchCheckChecked" checked>
            <label class="form-check-label" for="flexSwitchCheckChecked">Male</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check form-switch">
            <input class="form-check-input check-color6 bg-dark" type="checkbox" role="switch"
                id="flexSwitchCheckChecked" checked>
            <label class="form-check-label" for="flexSwitchCheckChecked">Male</label>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: When linking to your own site or content (or content that you are affiliated with), you [must disclose your affiliation _in the answer_](/help/promotion) in order for it not to be considered spam. Having the same text in your username as the URL or mentioning it in your profile is not considered sufficient disclosure under Stack Exchange policy.